# Shortest way to slice even/odd lines from a python array?

Tags: python, arrays

Or, a more general question would be, how to slice an array to get every n-th line, so for even/odd you'd want to skip one line, but in the general case you'd want to get every n-th lines, skipping n-1 lines.

Comment: i realize i can do it in a loop with it but i was wondering if i could just do it in one line instead

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a *list*, you specify the step in the slice (and start index). The syntax is `list[start:end:step]`.

You probably know the normal list access to get an item, e.g. `l[2]` to get the third item. Giving two numbers and a colon in between, you can specify a *range* that you want to get from the list. The return value is another list. E.g. `l[2:5]` gives you the third to sixth item. You can also pass an optional third number, which specifies the step size. The default step size is one, which just means *take every item* (between start and end index).

Example:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l[::2]         # even  - start at the beginning at take every second item
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> l[1::2]        # odd - start at second item and take every second item
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

See [lists in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

If you want to get every *`n`-th* element of a list (i.e. excluding the first element), you would have to slice like `l[(n-1)::n]`.

Example:

```
>>> l = range(20)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Now, getting every third element would be:

```
>>> l[2::3]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```

If you want to include the first element, you just do `l[::n]`.

Comment: I've never seen that before. The first number is the initial index and the last is the step then? Does anything go between the `::`? Or are both of them an operator, which is different from `:`? If I do `l[::1]` I get the original array then?

Comment: @fatcat - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange, see notes 3 & 5

Comment: @fatcat: Yes you would get the original array. I'd say more often you see just a slice from a start to an end index, like `l[2:5]`. The step is optional.

Answer (score 1):

This is more for me as a complete example ;)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ret = [[1,2], [3,4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
>>> itertools.izip_longest(*ret)
>>> [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(tmp) if x is not None]
[1, 3, 7, 8, 2, 4, 9, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

example for indices 0,2,4... of myArr

```
myArr[list(range(0,len(myArr),2))]
```

example for indices 1,3,5... of myArr

```
myArr[list(range(1,len(myArr)+1,2))]
```

you can manipulate it anyway you want with the step parameter, in this case it is equal to 2.
hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

```
> map(lambda index: arr[index],filter(lambda x: x%n == 0,range(len(arr))))
```

where `arr` is a list, and `n` slices are required.

Comment: -1 for using `map()` and `filter()` with a `lambda`. This is discouraged/slow and should **always** be done using a list comprehension.

Comment: Are there any experiments to back this claim?

Comment: I think there's a post from guido van rossum somewhere in the python mailing list archives about it. Anyway, it's kind of obvious since it's function call vs. no function call. Unless you are using Stackless calling functions is rather expensive