# Is there anything wrong with my code

Tags: python

```
def isbn10(x):
    y = [int(i) for i in x]
    a = y[0] * 10 + y[1] * 9 + y[2] * 8 + y[3] * 7 + y[4] * 6 + y[5] * 5 + y[6] * 4 + y[7] * 3 + y[8] * 2
    checkno = a % 11
    checkno = 11 - checkno
    if checkno == 10:
        checkno = "X"
    if checkno == prompt[9]:
        print("Your ISBN10 number is correct.")
    else:
        print("Your check number is wrong. It should be " + prompt[0:9] + checkno)


def isbn13(x):
    y = [int(i) for i in x]
    even = y[1] + y[3] + y[5] + y[7] + y[9] + y[11]
    odd = y[0] + y[2] + y[4] + y[6] + y[8] + y[10]
    even = even * 3
    total = even + odd
    checksum = total % 10
    checksum = 10 - checkno
    if checksum == prompt[-1]:
        print("Your ISBN13 number is correct.")
    else:
        print("Your check number is wrong. It should be " + prompt[0:-2] + checkno)
    #ok...


def main():
    prompt = input("Please type in your ISBN number.\n")
    prompt = str(prompt)

    if len(prompt) == 10:
        isbn10(prompt)
    elif len(prompt) == 13:
        isbn13(prompt)
    else:
        print("Your ISBN number is invalid")


while True:
    main()
    if input('Continue? [y/n]') == 'n':
        break
```

***When I run the program...:***

Please type in your ISBN number.
9876543210

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yc\Desktop\Computing\computing\python\Python ISBN\isbn_checker.py", line 29, in <module>
    isbn10(prompt)
  File "C:\Users\yc\Desktop\Computing\computing\python\Python ISBN\isbn_checker.py", line 11, in isbn10
    print("Your check number is wrong. It should be " + prompt[0:9] + checkno)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You're trying to concatenate a string and integer object. (Use string formatting)

Comment: You are mixing numbers and strings in the same `checkno` variable. It is never healthy to do that, even in dynamic languages like Python.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a codereview; [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Actually lots of things are wrong with your code. The fact that you don't follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is one of them. And those `even` and `odd` lists.. seriously? You can build them in a [much nicer way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988002/shortest-way-to-slice-even-odd-lines-from-a-python-array)! Also, `y=[int(i) for i in x]` can be written `y = map(int, x)`

Comment: Please learn to format your code so that it would be readable to you and others, or at least do it before sharing your code on the internet. Here's something to get you started: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. I'll clean up the code in your question for now.

Comment: P.S. You should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`; this will always give you a string like you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very frequent beginner mistake, concatenating strings and numbers. It is too localized

Comment: why raw_input since im using Python3.3?

Answer (score 1):

`checkno` is an integer in this case, and you are trying to concatenate it with a string.

Replace `checkno` with `str(checkno)`:

```
print("Your check number is wrong. It should be " + prompt[0:9] + str(checkno))
```

or, better use `format()` instead of concatenation:

```
print("Your check number is wrong. It should be {}{}".format(prompt[0:9], checkno))
```

Also:

- `checkno` variable is not defined in `isbn13()` function
- there is no `main()` function in the program
- the code is difficult to read and understand. One of the reason is that it doesn't follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style at all

Comment: Or, if they're using Python3, then `print("Your check number is wrong. It should be", prompt[0:9], checkno)` or otherwise use suitable string formatting `.format` instead of concatenation and save mucking about with explicit conversions... but yeah... lots of things wrong with the OP's code ;)

Comment: `checkno` is only an integer *sometimes*, see `checkno = "X"`

Comment: `str()` or `{}` with `.format()` works fine in any case though

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Your check number is wrong. It should be " + prompt[0:9] + checkno)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Is actually pretty self explanatory, did you even read the error message?

First never store different types of information in the same variable.

Avoid concatenate with the `+` in Python use the build in formatting.

```
print("Your check number is wrong. It should be %s%d" % (prompt[0:9],checkno) )
```