# Converting a string into a list or dict in Python

Tags: python

I need to break the lines on the pair values and to convert it to a list or dictonary. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this in Python?

From this:

```
1
Petrov
2
Ivanov
3
Sidorov
```

to

```
["1", "Petrov"], ["2", "Ivanov"], ["3", "Sidorov"]
```

or dictonary:

```
{"1": "Petrov", "2": "Ivanov", "3": "Sidorov"}
```

Comment: How are the input lines given? In a file or in a list of strings?

Comment: list of strings. Delimiter "\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> strs = """1                            
Petrov
2
Ivanov
3
Sidorov"""
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(strs.splitlines())]*2))
{'2': 'Ivanov', '3': 'Sidorov', '1': 'Petrov'}
```

Related: [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This code will return you a dictionary:

```
inp = open("file")
d = dict()
k = list()
v = list()
for line in inp:
    if line.strip("\n").isdigit():
        k.append(line.strip("\n"))
    else:
        v.append(line.strip("\n"))
print dict(zip(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adds a little twist to hcwhsa's solution by manipulating odd and even items in list:

```
>>> s = "1\nPetrov\n2\nIvanov\n3\nSidorov"
>>> dict(zip(s.split("\n")[::2], s.split("\n")[1::2]))
{'1': 'Petrov', '3': 'Sidorov', '2': 'Ivanov'}
```

see [Shortest way to slice even/odd lines from a python array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988002/shortest-way-to-slice-even-odd-lines-from-a-python-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> strs = """1                            
Petrov
2
Ivanov
3
Sidorov"""
>>> i = iter(strs.split())
>>> {item: i.next() for item in i}
{'1': 'Petrov', '3': 'Sidorov', '2': 'Ivanov'}
```

or

```
>>> i = iter(strs.split())
>>> [[item, i.next()] for item in i]
[['1', 'Petrov'], ['2', 'Ivanov'], ['3', 'Sidorov']]
```