# Slicing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

x[::2]

what does the above command mean and how does it function?

Comment: Skips every other row, returns `0,2,4..nth` rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is more data, it return even rows only by [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988012/2901002):

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[0,1,2]])
print (x)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
3  0  1  2

print (x[::2])
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
2  7  8  9
```