# Get iterable of 2-tuples from even iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable, standard-library

Is there a function in the standard library, that can generate an iterable of 2-tuples of an iterable that is guaranteed to have an even amount of elements?

```
INPUT = 'ABCDEF'
OUTPUT = [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]
```

I could not find anything fitting within `itertools`.

Comment: ``list(zip(INPUT[::2], INPUT[1::2]))``, here is [`dupe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988012/4985099)

Comment: Doesn't the `grouper` recipe **in `itertools`** do that?

Comment: `OUTPUT = list(zip(*[iter(INPUT)]*2))`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks. I think I overcomplicated this in my head.

Comment: The referred question is old and refers to lists only. I don't want lists in general. Furthermore it refers to the use of `izip()`, which is no longer available.

Comment: [Read the answers, not the question](http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2016/11/27/good-questions). [Tihs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039300/5067311) is spot on, and has a link to docs. Yes, yes, it has an unfortunate `i` in `izip`, and the link is to python 2 docs. It takes one character to fix both, [here's the modern doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). This doesn't need a duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
INPUT = 'ABCDEF'
OUTPUT = list(zip(INPUT[0::2], INPUT[1::2]))
```

Comment: And this is not useful, since the general iterable is non-subscribtable.