# How to put a colon (:) after every second character?

Tags: python

I want to put `:` after every second character:

```
def maccim():
    l = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    macim = random.sample(l, 12)
    szo = ""
    for x in macim:
        szo += x
    print(szo)

maccim()
```

I want to get like this: `94:EA:60:F8:BC:2D`
as a mac address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `enumerate` when you put together the string:

```
import random

def maccim():
    list=["A","B","C","D","E","F","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    macim=random.sample(list,12)
    szo=""
    for index, x in enumerate(macim):
        szo+=x
        if (index+1)%2 == 0:
            szo+=":"
    szo = szo[:-1]
    print(szo)
maccim()
```

Then you can use the index to determine if you need to add an ':'

Comment: that would be good, but I don't know how to remove the : at the end of it
75:1A:C2:9E:DB:36:

Comment: This will add an addtional `:` after the last character

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can use `szo =szo[:-1]` after the loop to remove the last element from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Create couples of characters with slicing and then just [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them with a `:`:

```py
import random

def maccim():
    l = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    macim = ''.join(random.sample(l, 12))

    print(':'.join(macim[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(macim), 2)))
    
maccim()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with brutal way

```
for i in range(len(macim)):
    szo += macin[i]
    if i % 2 and i < len(macim) - 1:
        szo += ":"
```

or fancy way

```
def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return (l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))

...

":".join(chunks(macin, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using [`list splice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988012/4985099),

```
import random


def maccim():
    list_ = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
    ]
    macim = random.sample(list_, 12)

    return ":".join([i + j for i, j in zip(macim[::2], macim[1::2])])


print(maccim())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, if you wanted a simple one-liner using `zip` and `map`:

```
import string
import random

chars = random.sample(string.hexdigits[:16], 12)

':'.join(map(''.join, zip(chars[::2], chars[1::2])))
```

This will output:

```
'07:9d:b5:1c:84:ae'
```