# Combine Strings Into List

Tags: python

How can I combine every two rows of a string into a paired list of lists?

my code is getting strings from text file:

```
for fp in oxi_filepath:
    with open(fp, 'r') as dat_file:
        data = dat_file.readlines()

filteredData = list(filter(lambda x: any(True for c in keywords if c in x and 'Value="/' not in x
                                         and 'Value="27' not in x and 'd3333-3333d' not in x), data))

for row in filteredData:
    result = re.search(self.regexpattern, row)
    if result:
        ocr_micr_l.append(result.group(1))
```

print filtered data...Example

```
My name is Chris
I like Burgers
My name is John
I like Chicken
```

output

```
[['My name is Chris', 'I like Burgers'],['My name is John', 'I like Chicken']]
```

Comment: What form are the strings in when you start? Is it a text file, a literal string in your code, something else?

Comment: @Grismar i edited my post with more info. Its from a text file.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see - but by the time you want to pair them up, the lines are already in a list `filteredData`

Comment: @Grismar you are correct, i turned it into a string when i did the group(1). I added rest of my code.. I needed to grab that element because it returns a tuple of 3...which is why i did group(1).

Answer (score 0):

try, `splitlines` followed by [`list splicing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988012/4985099)

```
text = """My name is Chris
I like Burgers
My name is John
I like Chicken"""

text_split = text.splitlines()

print([[i, j] for i, j in zip(text_split[::2], text_split[1::2])])
```

---

```
[['My name is Chris', 'I like Burgers'], ['My name is John', 'I like Chicken']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `filteredData` is already a list of lines of text, the answer is straightforward:

```
result = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(filteredData[::2], filteredData[1::2])]
```

Note that if `filteredData` has an odd number of items, you may want to add an empty string to the end of it before doing this, as `zip()` will only pair up items if there's an item for both halves of the pair.